# Can I retrieve config values for SSIS from XML in a table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, configuration, ssis

My current client stores all of their configuration information for the enterprise applications in a single table that holds XML. They then use a custom built front end to maintain the configuration values.

I'm writing a fairly straight-forward import process for them using SSIS. I need to make the connection strings and some other information configurable and they want me to use their table. It seems like SSIS expects a file though. Is there any way that I can point SSIS to retrieve its configuration values from an XML stream instead of a path to a file?

The configuration table that they use does not match the structure of a standard SSIS configuration table that you would get using SQL Server as a configuration source with the standard wizard.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve values from the table, put it in variables, and using a script, transfer the varaibale values into the SSIS parameters.

Having the XML formatted just like the SSIS XML file is a huge bonus, though.

Comment: I guess this is the only way.

Comment: So far it looks like this is the best way, although I'm trying to use XPath through an XML task to fill my other package variables. I'll let you know if I'm able to get it to work. Pretty close, but I'm getting extraneous escape characters in my string.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using an XML Task and XPath. It took a bit of monkeying around, but it works like a charm now. Had to add a script to remove trailing carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a away to put a trigger on thier table to update the SQL Server config table or create a new XML document anytime an SSIS configuration is inserted or updated? Then you could use what you need and they could do what they need and all would be happy.